# How to load a file by relative path in python?

Tags: python

My directory structure like below:

```
./outputsetting.json
./myapp/app.py
```

I load outputsetting.json file in app.py like below:

```
with open("..\outputpath.json","r") as f:
    j=json.load(f)
```

And run in myapp directory it's ok:

```
python app.py
```

But if I run app.py in the parent directory:

```
python .\myapp\app.py
```

It raise error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\outputpath.json'
```

How can I load file from disk by the relative directory to the app.py? So I can run it from any place and needn't modify code every time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the script from the parent directory, the *working directory* for the script changes. If you want to access a file that has a specific location relative to the script itself, you can do this:

```
from pathlib import Path

location = Path(__file__).parent
with open(location / "../outputsetting.json","r") as f:
    j=json.load(f)
```

`Path(__file__)` gets the location of the script it is executed in. The `.parent` thus gives you the folder the script is in, still as a `Path` object. And you can then navigate to the parent directory from that with `location / "../etc"`

Or of course in one go:

```
with open(Path(__file__).parent / "../outputsetting.json","r") as f:
    j=json.load(f)
```

(Note: your code says `outputpath.json`, but I assume that's the same `outputsetting.json`)

Another solution would be to just change the working directory to be the folder the script is in - but that of course only works if all your scripts and modules are OK with that change:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import chdir

chdir(Path(__file__).parent)
with open("../outputsetting.json","r") as f:
    j=json.load(f)
```

I'd prefer constructing the absolute path as in the previous example though.